# Different behaviours when intercepting throwed error in switch default or case (React/Redux)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have this reducer and these two middleware's

```
...

const reducer  = (
    state = {
        username : '',
        token : '?'
    }, 
    action
) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'SET_TOKEN': 
            state = { ...state, token : action.payload }
            break
        case 'SET_USERNAME': 
            state = { ...state, username : action.payload }
            break
        case 'SET_USERNME': 
            throw new Error("Errore, nessuna azione corrispondente")
            break               
    }
    return state
}

const logger = (store) => (next) =>(action) => {

  console.log(store, next, action);
  next(action);

}

const error = (store) => (next) =>(action) => {
  try{
    console.log("Checking errors");
    next(action);
  }catch(e){
    console.log("Error is: " +e);
  }
}

const middleware = applyMiddleware(logger, error);

...
```

Now when I dispatch an action 'SET_USERNME' to it, I receive the error message to my console that says: there is an error but the app continue to work. But I can't understand why. if I change the switch part as so, I do not receive a console message anymore but an error.

```
    switch (action.type){
        case 'SET_TOKEN': 
            state = { ...state, token : action.payload }
            break
        case 'SET_USERNAME': 
            state = { ...state, username : action.payload }
            break
        default: 
            throw new Error("Errore, nessuna azione corrispondente")
            break               
    }
```

Comment: Generally speaking, reducer must be implemented as pure function. Throwing an exception is not pure behaviour.  Also, both switch statements are the same. https://www.diffchecker.com/MDUjoqBN

Comment: Thanks for the advice Yury, i've updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following. The later implementation will throw an error for **any** action of a type it doesn't know.

When creating a store redux dispatches [`@@redux/INIT<SomeRandomString>`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/utils/actionTypes.js#L16) action to get initial state. But your reducer will throw failing entire bootstrap process. So your application wont start at all.

```
switch (action.type){
    case 'SET_TOKEN': 
        state = { ...state, token : action.payload }
        break
    case 'SET_USERNAME': 
        state = { ...state, username : action.payload }
        break
    default: // this will throw for redux init action as well.
        throw new Error("Errore, nessuna azione corrispondente")
        break               
}
```

Check this [comment](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/utils/actionTypes.js#L1-L6)

> ```
> /**
>  * These are private action types reserved by Redux.
>  * For any unknown actions, you must return the current state.
>  * If the current state is undefined, you must return the initial state.
>  * Do not reference these action types directly in your code.
>  */
> ```

Esp pay attention to **For any unknown actions, you must return the current state.** and **If the current state is undefined, you must return the initial state.**